# How to serialize a request?

Tags: java, rest, request, jax-rs

I have the request below, if occurs an error at the service I'd like to save in a database the request serialized to send again in other moment.

```
        URI uri = fromUri(config.getUri()).path("/myservice").build();
        Client client = ClientProducer.get();

        response = client
                .target(uri)
                .request()
                .headers(obterCabecalhos())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(Entity.json(myEntity));

        if (response.getStatus() != OK.getStatusCode()) {
            throw new TSEIntegracaoException();
             // Here I'd like to serialize the request and save in a database
        }
```

Comment: which rest provider are you using?

Comment: I am using JAX-RS

Comment: What's exact ClientProducer import in your class?

Comment: I do not think that is possible. You could create your own class that encapsulate your request data (uri, headers, method, payload) and serialize the instance of that class instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think that is possible. How about creating a class that encapsulate your request data (uri, headers, payload) and serializing the instance of that class instead.

An example:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class DemoClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

        URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:8000");
        Map<String, List<Object>> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, Arrays.asList((Object) MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        PostRequestData requestData = new PostRequestData(uri, headers, new String("hello world"));

        Response response = requestData.post(client);
        if (response.getStatus() != Status.ACCEPTED.getStatusCode()) {

            // let's serialise it into binary
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteStream);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(requestData);
            // save bytestream or print it?
            String bin = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(byteStream.toByteArray());
            System.out.println(bin);

            // let's replay the request
            byte[] newBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(bin);
            ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(newBytes));
            PostRequestData newRequestdata = (PostRequestData) oin.readObject();

            Response newResponse = newRequestdata.post(client);

            if (newResponse.getStatus() != Status.ACCEPTED.getStatusCode()) {
                System.out.println("give up!");
            }
        }
    }

    static class PostRequestData implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5786067257552259115L;

        final URI uri;

        final Map<String, List<Object>>  headers;

        final Serializable entity; 

        public PostRequestData(URI uri, Map<String, List<Object>> headers, Serializable entity) {
            this.uri = uri;
            this.headers = headers;
            this.entity = entity;
        }

        public Response post(Client client) {
            MultivaluedHashMap<String, Object> multimap = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, Object>();
            headers.forEach((k,v) -> multimap.put(k, v));

            return client.target(uri)
                .request()
                .headers(multimap)
                .post(Entity.text(entity));
        }

    }

}
```